# Reflection and Generics in .Net

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, .net-4.0

Ok...

I have the following interfaces:

- `IJobWrapper(Of T As IJob)`
- `IJob`

And the following abstracts:

- `JobWrapper(Of T as IJob)` (Implements `IJobWrapper(Of T)`)
- `Job1` (Implements `IJob`)
- `Job2` (Implements `IJob`)

So... First I find the wrapper abstract using:

```
Dim JobWrappers = AppDomain.
CurrentDomain.
GetAssemblies().
ToList().
SelectMany(Function(s) s.GetTypes()).
Where(Function(x) x.FullName.Contains("JobWrapper") And Not X.IsInterface).
First
```

This works fine (I'm aware it's a little inefficient but I can tidy it up when I've got a working version).

Then I use reflection to get all types which implement `IJob` (Similar to the above, I won't post code unless you need it) And do...

```
    For Each JobType In JobTypes
        Dim TypeArgs As Type() = {JobType.GetType}
        Dim WrappedJob = JobWrapperType.MakeGenericType(TypeArgs)
        ''Do some other stuff
    Next
```

This throws an exception. Specifically, this call:

`JobWrapperType.MakeGenericType(TypeArgs)`

Results in: `GenericArguments[0], 'System.RuntimeType', on 'MyProject.Jobs.JobWrapper'1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.`

Now in this case, `Job1` implements `IJob`. `JobWrapper` expects an `IJob` as it's type parameter.

Can someone please tell me how I can get a reference to the Types:

`JobWrapper(Job1)` and `JobWrapper(Job2)`

Thanks

As a little background: I'm loading assemblies into a new AppDomain and then loading all the `IJobs` from the assemblies loaded into that domain - hence having to use reflection. The Interfaces mentioned are defined in a common assembly referenced by both the current project and the ones containing the actual implementations of Job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got one too many `GetType`s - I think you just need:

```
For Each JobType In JobTypes
    Dim TypeArgs As Type() = {JobType}
    Dim WrappedJob = JobWrapperType.MakeGenericType(TypeArgs)
    ''Do some other stuff
Next
```

Comment: You're absolutely right - I've been staring at that bit of code for over an hour and didn't spot it. Thank you

Comment: @Will It looks weird to this C# dev too, but I assumed that the code compiles OK

Comment: @Will and Tim it is indeed valid - It's initialising an array so I could do: `Dim MyArray As Object() = {Var1, Var2, ..., Varn}`. In this instance I've only got the one type parameter - which I agree looks a little odd for VB

Comment: In case you're interested, follow-up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077573