# .Net Loading Generics using Reflection then Casting

Tags: generics, reflection, .net-4.0, unity-container

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069309/reflection-and-generics-in-net/5069326). Only bother reading it if you're interested in the back-story.

In short, I am using reflection to load a set of generic types from an assembly. The assembly is loaded at run time.

I have a second assembly referenced both by my current project and the assembly I'm loading which contains the interfaces:

- `IJob`
- `IJobWrapper(Of IJob)`

The Assembly I'm loading (Call it `Jobs.dll`) contains a `JobWrapper(Of IJob)` - which implements the `IJobWrapper` interface.

`Jobs.dll` also contains multiple jobs which implement `IJob`

Now, I'm loading the appropriate Types into a container (Unity) and pulling them out when required. This works (that is to say, the container resolves the references as appropriate and instantiates an object)

NB: `JobType` and `JobWrapperType` below are retrieved via reflection.

Specifically:

```
        Dim TypeArgs As Type() = {JobType}
        Dim WrappedJob = JobWrapperType.MakeGenericType(TypeArgs)
        Dim ContainerJob = Container.Resolve(WrappedJob)
        Dim JobInstance = DirectCast(ContainerJob, IJobWrapper(Of IJob))
```

What's throwing an error here is the last line with the cast.

`ContainerJob` on line 3 is technically an object as I need to use the non-generics overload to do the resolution (ie a Type parameter not an '(Of XXX)').

According to the debugger, however it's actually a `MyProject.Jobs.JobWrapper(Of MyProject.Jobs.DailyStatusReport)`

`MyProject.Jobs.JobWrapper` Implements `IJobWrapper(Of IJob)`
`MyProject.Jobs.DailyStatusReport` Implements `IJob`

The DirectCast throws this exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MyProject.Jobs.JobWrapper`1[MyProject.Jobs.DailyStatusReport]' to type 'MyProject.JobService.Common.IJobWrapper`1[MyProject.JobService.Common.IJob]'.
```

Can someone please explain why it can't do the cast / how to get around it? I'm wondering if it is having trouble matching the Interface defined in the referenced assembly with the one referenced from within `Jobs.dll` - But if that is the case, I'm unsure how to reconcile the two.

Many thanks.

EDIT:

Sample methods from the interfaces:

IJob:

```
Function ShouldExectute() As Boolean
Sub Execute()
```

IJobWrapper:

```
Function ShouldExectute() As Boolean
Sub Execute()
ReadOnly Property DatabaseId as Long
ReadOnly Property Name as String
ReadOnly Property IsDisabled As Boolean
```

Eg - The Job Wrapper doesn't ever return anythign with the type of the IJob. It does use the type information to look up various Attributes which have been attached to the class which implements IJob and read information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to perform this cast (with or without reflection) because generic type parameters are required to match exactly. So you could cast an `AnyImplementationOfIJobWrapper(Of IJob)` to `IJobWrapper(Of IJob)`, but you can not cast an `AnyImplementationOfIJobWrapper(Of AnyImplementationOfIJob)` to `IJobWrapper(Of IJob)`.

However, if you control the code for `IJobWrapper`, you can turn it into a [*covariant* interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx) by declaring it as `Interface IJobWrapper(Of Out IJob)`. This will allow you to perform the cast. It is the same mechanism that allows you to e.g. assign an `IEnumerable(Of Subclass)` to `IEnumerable(Of Superclass)`.

(Feel free to correct any syntax mistakes I might have made; it's been a while since I used VB.)

A natural question would be "Why is not this cast allowed in the first place?" The reason is that it would lead to dangerous situations: Assume that you have an `IList(Of Vehicle) vehicles`. It seems natural that it should be possible to assign a `List(Of Car)` to `vehicles`, since a list of cars could be considered a list of vehicles. But if we allow `vehicles` to refer to what is truly a `List(Of Car)`, we could try to add a `Boat` to `vehicles`, which should be allowed since `vehicles` appears to be a list of `Vehicle`s and a `Boat` is a `Vehicle`. However, the actual list is restricted to only contain `Car`s, so we must either throw an exception (very unexpected for the user of `vehicles`) or insert the `Boat` into a list of `Car`s (creating a disaster waiting to happen). Solution: disallow the cast. `IEnumerable` (but not `IList`) can be made covariant because it only contains methods that lets you read from the collection. Therefore, an `IEnumerable(Of Car)` can be assigned to an `IEnumerable(Of Vehicle)` because `IEnumerable` only lets you read contents of the collection, not insert new objects into it.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be exactly the problem I'm hitting (and one I've never come across before oddly). I do indeed control the `Jobs.dll` - Can you please give an example of the code required to make this work?

Comment: In case it helps, I'll add a summary of the methods on the interfaces to my question

Comment: I assume that your declaration of `IJobWrapper` looks like this: `Interface IJobWrapper(Of IJob)`. In that case, it should suffice to add the keyword `Out` to make the interface covariant: `Interface IJobWrapper(Of Out IJob)`. However, co- and contravariance was introduced in .NET 4.0 and will presumably not work in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Luckily I'm using .Net 4

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks - Now I just need to go away and understand what it's doing...

Comment: Glad to hear it. It takes a little time to wrap one's head around the concept; fortunately, there are [plenty](http://blog.t-l-k.com/dot-net/2009/c-sharp-4-covariance-and-contravariance) of [blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) and [videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee672314.aspx) (as well as other StackOverflow questions) on the subject.

Comment: Also, [Jon Skeet held an excellent presentation about co- and contravariance](http://streaming.ndc2010.no/tcs/?id=F36BD4C5-4FB7-4C1B-A0E1-990DA59308F5) at the Norwegian Developers Conference 2010. The site seems quite unstable now, so you might need a few tries before the video loads, but it's worth the effort.